# Using Postgres enum with Quill

Tags: postgresql, scala, enums, implicit, quill

I'm trying to use a Scala 2 enum with Quill, like so:

```scala
import io.getquill.MappedEncoding

object MyEnumType extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnumType = Value

  val ONE, TWO, THREE = Value

  implicit val encode: MappedEncoding[MyEnumType, String] =
    MappedEncoding(_.toString)
  implicit val decode: MappedEncoding[String, MyEnumType] =
    MappedEncoding(MyEnumType.withName)
}
```

But I'm ending up with an error from Postgres:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: my_enum_type = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm printing out the query using `translate`, and the query is generated like so:

```sql
WHERE column_1 = ONE
```

Where I'm *expecting* it to be rendered like:

```sql
WHERE column_1 = 'ONE'
```

What's the proper way to handle enums with Quill in Scala 2.13?

### Edit

I have been experimenting, including using the [Enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum#quill) library, and enum values are still not being generated correctly.

Using the debugger, I can see that the custom encoder is being evaluated, but the result value never makes it to the generated query.

I have posted an example of the problem here:
https://gist.github.com/daharon/97e8b167911723054ac3845fc35c0b11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that by default the enum value was being generated as a `java.sql.Types.VARCHAR` by Quill.
Hence the error, `operator does not exist: my_enum_type = character varying`, since Postgres didn't know how to convert a `character varying` to my custom Postgres `enum` type.

The solution was to force Quill to encode the value as `java.sql.Types.OTHER`.

```scala
object Ctx extends PostgresJdbcContext(SnakeCase)

object MyEnumType extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnumType = Value

  val ONE, TWO, THREE = Value

  import Ctx.*
  
  implicit val enc: Encoder[MyEnumType] = encoder(
    java.sql.Types.OTHER,
    (index, value, row) => row.setObject(index, value.toString, java.sql.Types.OTHER)
  )

  implicit val dec: Decoder[MyEnumType] =
    decoder(row => index => this.withName(row.getObject(index).toString))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add quotes

```
implicit val encode: MappedEncoding[MyEnumType, String] =
  MappedEncoding(x => s"'$x'")
implicit val decode: MappedEncoding[String, MyEnumType] =
  MappedEncoding(s => MyEnumType.withName(s.stripPrefix("'").stripSuffix("'")))
```

Comment: Trying your suggestion seems to have revealed that Quill is not finding my custom encoder/decoder at all.  I'm not sure where to place these `implicit` values, now.

Comment: @daharon Yeah, you should `import MyEnumType._`. `object MyEnumType` is not a companion object because `type MyEnumType` is a type, not class. So `object MyEnumType` is not in implicit scope.

Comment: @daharon Does importing `MyEnumType._` help? If so, does it work with your original codecs or my codecs with quotes?

Comment: I was wrong. There's no need to import `MyEnumType._`. Implicits can be seen although `object MyEnumType` is not a companion. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/Z9CSo2UbSmKraNX8du5yZw/1 This is because `MyEnumType.MyEnumType` is `MyEnumType.type#MyEnumType`. *"The parts of a type `T` are: ... if `T` is a type projection `S#U`, the parts of `S` as well as `T` itself;"* https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html#implicit-parameters